# Problem with a limit with a integral in it

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose that the temperature in a long thin rod placed along the $x$-axis is initially $\frac{C}{2a}$ if $|x| \leq a$ and $0$ if $|x| > a$. It can be shown that if the heat diffusivity of the rod is $k$, then the temperature of the rod at the point $x$ at time $t$ is
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} T(x,t) = \frac{C}{a\sqrt{4\pi kt}} {\large \int}_{0}^a {\large e}^{\dfrac{-(x−u)^2}{4kt}}du$$

First I tried to calculate the integral and I got: $$-\frac{4kt\cdot {\large e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4kt}}}}{(x-u)^2} $$
then I tried substituting it in the original function but it became really messed up after I tried to solve it using the L'Hôspital rule

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `C`, a controlled symbol (in *Mathematica*).  This is clearly an error function integral:

```
Integrate[c/(a Sqrt[4 π k t]) Exp[-(x - u)^2/(4 k t)], {u, 0, a}]
```

$\frac{c \sqrt{k} \sqrt{t} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{a-x}{2 \sqrt{k}
   \sqrt{t}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{k} \sqrt{t}}\right)\right)}{2 a \sqrt{k t}}$